# How to convert SQL query to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server

**Background:**

Writing a Ruby on Rails app that is connect to MS SQL DB(don't ask why, its something I cant get around), the DB is quiet large and can have up to 2/3 million rows.

There is one main columns that matter for me at the moment and that is 'TimeUTC' and the table is called ApplicationLog and the query will be in the ApplicationLogController.

**Problem:**

I want to write a query that i can pass in two dates and it will group all the records by day using the 'TimeUTC' column and gives me a total of all the records for those days in between those two dates.

I have the SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime = '2014-01-04 00:00:00' 
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime = '2014-02-04 23:59:59' 

select (dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, TimeUtc))) as [DATE], count(*) 
from applicationlog (nolock)
where TimeUtc between @StartDate and  @EndDate 
group by dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, TimeUtc))
order by [DATE] desc
```

I try starting with something like this:

```
@results = ApplicationLog.select((dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, TimeUtc)) as [date], count(*)).
           group(dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, TimeUtc))).order(date desc)
```

Now I am a newbie at this so I could be so far off the track its not funny, but any help would be great.  Am I even going about this the right way, is there a better way??

Comment: this should get you started:   


`ApplicationLog.where(time_utc: start_date..end_date).group(time_utc).order('time_utc desc').count`

Comment: Note that your might need to specify your table name in your model, and rename your `TimeUtc` column to `time_utc` which is rails standard, or use `timeutc` instead of `time_utc` as I specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code, which uses Arel code with some SQL embedded.

```
class ApplicationLog < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.between(range)
    columns = Arel.sql('dateadd(DAY,0,datediff(day,0,TimeUtc)) as date, COUNT(*)')
    conditions = arel_table['TimeUTC'].in(range)
    query = arel_table.project(columns).where(conditions).group([1]).order('date desc')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query.to_sql)
  end
end
```

Then use `ApplicationLog.between(1.week.ago..Time.now)`.

Comment: I used your code but change it a little just to get it to work with something simple:(put below in model)
def self.between_dates(date)
    columns = Arel.sql('dateadd(DAY,0,datediff(day,0,TimeUtc)) as date, COUNT(*)')
    conditions = arel_table['TimeUTC'].eq(date)
    query = arel_table.select(columns).where(conditions).group([1]).order('date desc')
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query.to_sql).values
  end
Then in my view i just put <%= ApplicationLog.between(Time.now) %>
when I load my page I get 
private method `select' called for #<Arel::Table:0x007fb725fb6ce0>
any ideas??

Comment: I updated my answer to use a BETWEEN statement by using arel's #in method

Comment: Thats working now and the correct sql is being executed, but it never returns anything then -1

Comment: what do you mean by anything? I removed the #values call, you should call it from outside: ApplicationLOg.between(from..to).values

Comment: So when I call ApplicationLog.between(from..to).values from my view i get:
undefined method `values' for -1:Fixnum
If I call ApplicationLOg.between(from..to)
My view displays just -1

I am using arel (3.0.3) and other question is do I need to put ApplicationLog.between(from..to).values in a for each loop?

Comment: Figured it out, because I am using tidy_tds I need to use the .select_all method on the ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query.to_sql)

So it would be ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(query.to_sql)